# tslint not working properly via npm script

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

Im configuring a tslint for my project. while the tslint woks well when ran in command prompt. but fails when run via npm scripts.

1. On command prompt

   > ```
   > ip-192-168-14-138:scripture-cite vinodlouis$ tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.ts
   >
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[1, 23]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[2, 1]: Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[2, 26]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[3, 25]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[4, 1]: Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[4, 29]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[12, 5]: comment must start with a space
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[21, 29]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[31, 9]: Identifier 'router' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[33, 16]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[35, 18]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[35, 32]: Missing trailing comma
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[38, 22]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/App.ts[43, 34]: file should end with a newline
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[1, 23]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[2, 1]: Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[2, 24]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[4, 17]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[6, 7]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[9, 9]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[13, 11]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[14, 11]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[17, 7]: Shadowed name: 'port'
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[17, 7]: Identifier 'port' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[17, 38]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[18, 3]: if statements must be braced
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[19, 8]: if statements must be braced
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[20, 3]: else statements must be braced
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[24, 3]: if statements must be braced
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[24, 25]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[25, 7]: Identifier 'bind' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[25, 31]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[25, 43]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[25, 60]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[26, 9]: missing whitespace
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[27, 10]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[28, 7]: Calls to 'console.error' are not allowed.
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[31, 10]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[32, 7]: Calls to 'console.error' are not allowed.
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[41, 7]: Identifier 'addr' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[42, 7]: Identifier 'bind' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[42, 31]: ' should be "
   > ERROR: src/index.ts[44, 2]: file should end with a newline
   > ```
2. Via npm script

   > ```
   > ip-192-168-14-138:scripture-cite vinodlouis$ npm run lint
   >
   > > scripture-cite@1.0.0 lint /Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite
   > > tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.ts
   >
   > The 'comment-format' rule threw an error in 'src/App.ts':
   > TypeError: ts.forEachLeadingCommentRange is not a function
   >     at /Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:403:16
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:366:20)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at forEachToken (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:369:7)
   >     at Object.forEachComment (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:399:12)
   > The 'jsdoc-format' rule threw an error in 'src/App.ts':
   > TypeError: ts.forEachLeadingCommentRange is not a function
   >     at /Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:403:16
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:366:20)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at forEachToken (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:369:7)
   >     at Object.forEachComment (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:399:12)
   > TypeError: ts.forEachLeadingCommentRange is not a function
   >     at /Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:403:16
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:366:20)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   >     at iterate (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
   >     at forEachToken (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:369:7)
   >     at Object.forEachComment (/Users/vinodlouis/projects/rb/scripture-cite/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:399:12)
   > npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   > npm ERR! errno 1
   > npm ERR! scripture-cite@1.0.0 lint: `tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.ts`
   > npm ERR! Exit status 1
   > npm ERR! 
   > npm ERR! Failed at the scripture-cite@1.0.0 lint script.
   > npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   >
   > npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   > npm ERR!     /Users/vinodlouis/.npm/_logs/2018-07-19T06_16_52_537Z-debug.log
   > ```

configuration file are as follows:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "scripture-cite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp scripts",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec --compilers ts:ts-node/register 'test/**/*.test.ts'",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "0.0.33",
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/chai-http": "^0.0.29",
    "@types/debug": "0.0.29",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.37",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.0.49",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.32",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.32",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.3",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.1",
    "lint": "^1.1.2",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

tslint.json

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules"
        ]
    },
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {},
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3113. TSLint requires typescript@>=2.1.0 to work. You're currently using ^2.0.6. Did you not see any errors on install?

Comment: @N.Faure Thanks that works!